# Use string as a filename

Tags: android, string, filenames, filewriter

I need a help. I have an android app. I am using editText to get string. 
Then I create a file something.txt and write data in it.
How Can I set file name to mystring.txt ?

```
try {
        writer = new FileWriter(root + "/filename.txt",true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need it cause I need to have all data with different filename for my app...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use

```
String desiredFileName = edittext.getText().toString();
try {
    writer = new FileWriter(root + "/" + desiredFileName + ".txt",true);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Mirko You should follow some tutorials, it would really help you. Also please accept the answer if it solves it

Comment: Hi, I know i should follow tutorial but now I need to make this program work and I am still learning :/

Can you help me with it ?
I do not know how to save text from editTxt (id of my editText) to string. I can't us findviewbyid in service... :/
Any idea ?

Comment: @Mirko the findViewById is a method of view. You call it on the layout view which contains the EditText

Comment: I tried it but it gives me error...
i tried to call it in mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Do u want to define the Filename in the EditText?

If yes, what about this:

```
try {
    writer = new FileWriter(root + "/" + editText.getText(), true);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If not, please try to explain it a bit more detailed.